# asp button OnClientClick fails ie 10

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the code below, that I use to submit data to the server, I disable the button so the member not able to click the button multiple times (avoid multiple submissions) and i show moving image "in progress so the member knows something is happening.. "

The code works in firefox, ie 8,9 but fails on ie 10, what happens it kinda gets stuck on that page and doesnt go to the next page...

asp.net code

```
<p id="pInprogress" style="display: none">
                <img src="images/PleaseWait.gif" style="width: 30px;" id="imgWait" runat="server" />
 </p>


 <asp:Button ID="btNext"
         runat="server" 
         Text="Next"
         OnClick="btNext_Click" 
          OnClientClick="this.disabled = true; this.value = 'Submit in progress...'; inprogress();" 
          UseSubmitBehavior="false"  />
```

javascript function

```
    function inprogress() {
        document.getElementById("pInprogress").style.display = "";          
    }
```

any ideas why it fails....

thank you

Comment: Check your console for possible errors.

Comment: thanks! i checked, it says SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'disabled' of undefined or null reference 
SCRIPT5009: 'WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions' is undefined 
 what does it mean?

Comment: Your code is working fine in my IE10 with VS2012. [IE10 causing _doPostBack](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx) is an old bug and has been fixed. Please make sure you are using last .Net Framework.

Comment: worked! how do I mark it solved?

Comment: @Ben, You should post what worked for you as an answer, and accept your own answer.